# Каждой строке в таблице свой фон. jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, table

Имеется таблица с входными параметрами.

```
<table id="table">
<tr>
    <td>str1</td>
    <td>str2</td>
    <td>color1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>str4</td>
    <td>str5</td>
    <td>color2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>str7</td>
    <td>str8</td>
    <td>color1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>str10</td>
    <td>str11</td>
    <td>color2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>str13</td>
    <td>str14</td>
    <td>color3</td>
</tr>
```

В последнем столбце приходят данные color1, color2, color3.
Подскажите пожалуйста, как сделать так, зная значения последнего столбца, присваивать фон всей строке. 
Например, где color1 - фон красный, color2 - зеленый, color3 - желтый.

Начал так:

```
var items=[];

$('#table td:last-child').each( function(){
items.push($(this).text());      
});
var items = $.unique( items );
$.each( items, function(i, item){
 // switch? 
})
```

Начало правильное?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
let colours = {
  color1: 'red',
  color2: 'green',
  color3: 'blue'
};

$(_ => {
  $('table tr td:last-child').each((i, e) => {
    e = $(e);
    e.parent().css({
      background: colours[e.text()]
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="table">
  <tr>
    <td>str1</td>
    <td>str2</td>
    <td>color1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>str4</td>
    <td>str5</td>
    <td>color2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>str7</td>
    <td>str8</td>
    <td>color1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>str10</td>
    <td>str11</td>
    <td>color2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>str13</td>
    <td>str14</td>
    <td>color3</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Огромное вам спасибо.

Comment: Пожалуйста!....